# How to hyperlink a document property field in word 2016?

Tags: ms-word, word-2016

Document properties are fields that can be used throughout microsoft word: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/view-or-change-the-properties-for-an-office-file-21d604c2-481e-4379-8e54-1dd4622c6b75

Typically I use these fields throughout my document so changing the document property will change all instances of that field throughout my document.  This is great, however, when one of the fields is "Company Email" I not only want the text to change to employee@company.com but I would like to have that field hyperlinked to employee@company.com so that the user can click it in order to send an email.

**Edit**: (Info from comments)

I have tried to insert a hyperlink, hit alt-f and embed a docproperty via the instructions from a similar thread: stackoverflow.com/questions/17428891/…. But could not get that to work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works for me, in a quick test (you'll need to substitute the name of the Document Property you're using):

```
{ HYPERLINK "mailto:{ DocProperty Email }" }
```

When I Ctrl+Click this it creates a new Email to the address.

For readers unfamiliar with inserting field codes: The wavy bracket pairs *must* be inserted using Ctrl+F9. Alt+F9 after to switch from field code to field display.

Comment: Great stuff.  I think I was formatting the string that you posted above in an incorrect manner.  The above works great.  Thank you for your rapid replies!

Comment: You're welcome :-) Yes, hyperlinks can be "finicky" (spaces and things). And it took me a bit to remember the "mailto:" part...

Comment: So here is something interesting.  When I save this document, close out of word, and then reopen and try to update the docproperty field, the text changes but not the underlying hyperlink....  Inspecting the document with alt + F9 reveals that the `{ DocProperty Email }` has been replaced with whatever value it was when I saved and exited....

Comment: @quinlo I don't see this. In what order to you do things? Is there any code associated with the document? What are the settings for updating fields on open?

Comment: So this is working as I test in the document:

`{ HYPERLINK "mailto:{ DOCPROPERTY Email }" \* MERGEFORMAT }`

changing `Email` value will change both the displayed email and the underlying hyperlink correctly.  When I then save the .docx, exit out of word completely and reopen the .docx, changing the DocProperty `Email` will result in changing JUST the displayed value and not the underlying hyperlink.... the above string in alt + f9 mode is now just

`{ HYPERLINK "mailto:employee@company.com" }`